# Connect to External WebDAV with PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, webdav, put

Does anyone have resources/advice on how to connect to a third party WebDAV with PL/SQL? I will be placing a file onto their server and retrieving a log file. Is it as simple as using UTL_HTTP & 'PUT'?

Examples appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after further research, I decided to use PL/SQL to generate the file and CURL to transfer the file to the external server.